# How to print a unsigned char array from a pointer of a structure?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to call a function via function parameter. The function I'm trying to call takes a structure as a parameter. I'm able to call the desired function but while trying to print an `unsinged char` array, I'm getting `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

My code is,

```
//char_array.c


#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

# define SIZE 20

static struct test{
   unsigned char in[SIZE];
   unsigned char out[SIZE];
}teststruct;

int func2 (struct test *test_func2){
    printf("Inside func2 function\n");
    printf("Inside func2, msg is : %s\n", &test_func2->in);
    return 1;
}

void func1( struct test *test_func1, int (*f)(struct test)){
    printf("Inside func1, msg is:  %s\n", &test_func1->in);

    // calling function
    (*f)(*test_func1);
}

int main(){

    struct test test_main;
    memcpy(teststruct.in,"This is test ", sizeof(teststruct.in));

    test_main=teststruct;

    //check values
    printf("test_main.in is: %s\n", test_main.in);

    // calling func2 from func1
    func1(&test_main,func2);

}
```

**Output:**

```
$./char_array 
 test_main.in is: This is test 
 Inside func1, msg is:  This is test 
 Inside func2 function
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm compiling my code like following,

`gcc -O0 -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -o char_array char_array.c`

Any help what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: To begin, `memcpy(teststruct.in,"This is test ", sizeof(teststruct.in));` copies 20 bytes, but the source array (the string) is less than 20 bytes long.  Undefined behavior right there.

Comment: The second argument to `func1` is a pointer to a function whose single argument is of type `struct test`, but you pass it the address of `func2`, whose argument is of type `struct test *`.  So you end up passing the struct itself to `func2` whereas it is expecting a pointer.

Comment: You enabled a bunch of warnings, which is good, but did you actually look at them?  https://godbolt.org/z/6GM377 shows at least 5, all serious.  You really ought not to even try to run the program before you have addressed the compiler warnings.  The compiler warns you about the bug in my second comment, and if you enable optimizations (which helps it give better warnings), it warns about the first one too.

Comment: @NateEldredge `So you end up passing the struct itself to func2 whereas it is expecting a pointer`. I did not understand this line.

Comment: Inside `func1`, the variable `test_func1` is a pointer to `struct test`.  When you dereference it as `*test_func1`, you have an expression which is not a pointer but actually a `struct test`.  So it is incorrect to pass it to `func2`, since the first argument of `func2` is supposed to be a *pointer* to `struct test`.  This line should read `(*f)(test_func1);`, and should not have compiled if `f` had been declared with the correct type, but your second bug compounded the first.

Comment: If you intend to store small non-negative integers, use `unsigned char`. If you intend to store small possibly-negative integers, use `signed char`. If you intend to store characters, use `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `func2` is - `int (struct test *)` and you are passing `func2` pointer as 2<sup>nd</sup> argument to `func1()` whose 2<sup>nd</sup> parameter type is `int (*)(struct test)`. This is type mismatch. You need to make correction in 2<sup>nd</sup> parameter type of `func1()` function:

```
void func1( struct test *test_func1, int (*f)(struct test *))
                                                         ^^^
```

The parameter type of `func2()` function is - `struct test *`. That means, it can receive address of variable of type `struct test`. Here,

```
    // calling function
    (*f)(*test_func1);
```

pointer `f` hold the address of `func2()` function and argument that you are passing is of type `struct test`. Again the type mismatch. Instead, it should be

```
    // calling function
    (*f)(test_func1);
        ^^^
```

because the `test_func1` is of type `struct test *` which is same as the type of parameter of `func2()` function.

One more point, you don't need to give `&` with `test_func2->in` when printing its value in `func2()` function:

```
    printf("Inside func2, msg is : %s\n", test_func2->in);
                                         ^^^
```

Same is for `func1()` function when printing `test_func1->in`.